# comparison: on, over, when both of which imply 'in connection with'

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

> The United States has vowed to follow the Islamic State 'to the gates of hell' ***over*** the beheading of American journalists James Foley and Steven Sotloff.  ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4080587.htm))

When I consulting RHD’s ‘[ON prep. #4, #12](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on?s=t)’ and ‘[OVER prep. #19](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/over?s=t)’, the two usages seem to denote ‘*in connection with their complements*.’ What’s the difference between the two? Is it degree of intimacy? The former has more closeness with its complement and the latter less, I mean. But this isn’t that persuasive on my own, for the victims of beheading are her very own citizens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have identified the appropriate sense of *over*, #19; but the key to this use lies in the example there, not the definition: ‘to quarrel over a matter.’ *Over* is used in this sense specifically when the complement designates the cause of disagreement or strife.

> Wars are fought over religion, over political theories, over national identity—but mostly they are fought over money and land.
>
> The sisters wrangled bitterly over who would get their mother's silver.
>
> There was considerable debate in the summer of 1945 over the use of the new atomic weapon.

The extension of *over* complementation from verbs signifying conflict to similarly impassioned one-sided actions is fairly recent; it seems to be a particular favourite of journalists:

> White Marine Beaten Severely by Black Men for Revenge over Ferguson Shooting —headline, [*Newsiosity*](http://www.newsiosity.com/articles/society/white-marine-beaten-severely-black-men-revenge-over-ferguson-shooting)
>
> Mum's fight for justice over son's forestry death —headline, [*TVNZ*](http://tvnz.co.nz/national-news/mum-s-fight-justice-over-son-forestry-death-6070093)
>
> Rotherham: police need outside force to 'deliver justice' over child abuse, says Nick Clegg —headline, [*The Guardian*](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/11062099/Rotherham-police-need-outside-force-to-deliver-justice-over-child-abuse-says-Nick-Clegg.html)

I cannot recall *on* being used in contexts like these.

Comment: So I’m “_on_” this side and you can see a problem “_over_” the conflict between me and my opponent on the other side.

Comment: @Listenever Perzackly.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting "on" in place of "over" would not be correct in this context. The important part of the #4 definition of on is "as a part or element of". *"I am on the board of directors."* The definition of "over" in this context is "about" or "concerning". *"I was furious over the theft of my work."* or *"She clapped her hands with glee over the announcement."*

In general, the phrasing is used to explain an action related to some event or thing.

Comment: I need to change 'ON pep. #4' to 'On prep. #4 or #12' - _with respect or regard to_. You can see '_on_' is synonym with '_about_' and '_over_' ['here'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/on). For all the consulting, still we can't use 'on' on the sentence?